# variable scope and naming resolution

Tags: python, scope

I am a bit confused by how Python handles variable scope.

Below is a simple example that I created to explain the varialbe scope. When I execute the code below, the reference error surprisingly happens at the line `print(x)` instead of `x = x + 1`.

```
def foo():
    print(x)
    x = x + 1

x = 0
foo()
```

I would assume at the line `print(x)`, Python should have access to the x in the global scope, no? (In fact, if we comment out the line `x = x + 1`, the code actually runs)

How exactly does the Python intepreter work here?

Comment: If a variable is assigned to inside a function, then it is local to that function unless declared as `global`. It makes no difference whether the attempted read-only access to the variable is before or after the assignment statement.

Comment: @alani hmm, does that Python interpreter will parse the whole function before executing it?

Comment: Yes, the CPython interpreter runs byte code, not source code. Byte code is derived from compiling entire code blocks.